# What is the life cycle of a wart?

Tags: virology, pathology

There doesn't seem to be a lot of information available on research done on warts.  What is the life cycle of a wart?  How does it spread? -- specifically how does it recruit cells to spread it?  What is the life cycle of a PV-infected dermal cell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0365-05962011000200014&lng=en&nrm=iso&tlng=en) article has some good information. It's certainly more than I want to know about warts.

> Isolated warts may remain unaltered for
>   months or years, or a large number of new lesions
>   may develop rapidly in a short period of time. The
>   development of warts is not predictable.
>   Approximately 65% of warts disappear spontaneously
>   within two years. The patient’s age and number of
>   lesions do not seem to affect the prognosis.

There are many different types of [warts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wart) and of [HPV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus). Since warts cause a type of [dysplasia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysplasia) their life cycle can be very variable and unpredictable.

Comment: Do you mind summarize some of the key points in the article. The link might die someday, and it'd just make a much more complete answer :).

Comment: Sure. I'm new to Biology beta. It seems to me that the nature of the site necessitates a lot of linking and referencing since there's no way to confirm someone's credentials. And even those with credentials need to cite their sources.

Comment: Welcome :). Generally, when making a claim, a reference is just customary. The edited answer is great though, +1.

Answer (score 4):

Conner's response contained just the type of source material I was looking for.  Thanks Conner -- let us all +1 him.  Allow me to summarize the specifics of the [article](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0365-05962011000200014&lng=en&nrm=iso&tlng=en) in relation to my question:

**Transmission**

> PVs are transmitted through direct or indirect contact with an
>   individual who has the lesion. Dysfunctions in the epithelial barrier
>   by trauma, minor injuries or maceration cause loss of solution of
>   continuity in the skin, thus allowing viral infection. After
>   inoculation, the incubation period varies from 3 weeks to 8 months.
>   Spontaneous regression is observed in most cases.

**Infection**

> Infection begins when the PV reaches the cells of the basal layer;
>   there is no viral replication at this location and the virus just
>   keeps its genome by amplification of a low number of copies.

**Replication**

> The replicative phase and protein synthesis occur in the suprabasal
>   differentiated [keratinocytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratinocyte). Progression time and type of lesion
>   correlates with the quantity of viral particles detected. Younger
>   warts present a higher viral amount when compared to old warts.
>   Plantar warts have a higher viral load than common warts. The center
>   of the lesion appears to be the main site of viral concentration.

**Latency**

> PVs appear to remain in their host for long periods of life. A variety
>   of different types of PVs can be detected in random sites of normal
>   skin in humans and animals. This reinforces that a latent life cycle
>   is often a characteristic of these viruses.

**Interesting Notes**

- There are no known PVs that infect more than one species.
- To date, about 100 different types of HPVs have been fully characterized.
- Human PVs does not grow on conventional culture media. The diagnosis of HPV infection is made by histopathology of lesions